# How to pass a Classic ASP Scripting.Dictionary to a C# COM Class Library?

Tags: c#, dll, dictionary, asp-classic, com

I am working on a classic ASP application that was handed to me that I have to work with. I would like to use a component that is only in the .NET framework. I need to make a C# class library that can do the .NET code that can be called through the COM on classic ASP.

I would like to pass in a classic ASP dictionary into the C# com component. Best case would be to pass a dictionary of dictionaries. I have added Scripting.Dictionary from the com as a reference in my C# code.

Here is my current code.

Classic ASP:

```
Set test = Server.CreateObject("Reporting") 'This is my custom Object
Set dic = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dic.Add "Test", 1
test.GetReport 1, dic
```

C#:

```
public byte[] GetReport(int Report_Type_Requested, Scripting.DictionaryClass Report_Params)
        {
            try
            {
                return report.GetReport(Report_Params);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {               
                throw e;
            }                       
        }
```

But when I run this I get:

```
Message = "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'Scripting.DictionaryClass'. COM components that enter the CLR and do not support IProvideClassInfo or that do not have any interop assembly registered will be wrapped in the __ComObject ...
```

I've also tried this and it didn't seem to have worked:

```
public byte[] GetReport(int Report_Type_Requested, Dictionary Report_Params)
            {
                try
                {
                    return report.GetReport(Report_Params);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {               
                    throw e;
                }                       
            }
```

I thought this one might work but it tells me you can't cast it:

```
public byte[] GetReport(int Report_Type_Requested, object Report_Params)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return report.GetReport((Scripting.DictionaryClass)Report_Params);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {               
                        throw e;
                    }                       
                }
```

How can I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I tried using IDictionary like the following at got "Invalid Procedure call or argument":

```
 public byte[] GetReport(int Report_Type_Requested, IDictionary Report_Params)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            return report.GetReport(Report_Params);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {               
                            throw e;
                        }                       
                    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried using Scripting.IDictionary to specify it better. I got the same error "Invalid Procedure call or argument":

```
public byte[] GetReport(int Report_Type_Requested, Scripting.IDictionary Report_Params)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                return report.GetReport(Report_Params);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {               
                                throw e;
                            }                       
                        }
```

**EDIT 3:**

I added the code for Get Report. I keep changing the GetReport paramter to whatever I am testing.

```
public byte[] GetReport(Scripting.IDictionary Report_Params)
        {
           return null;
        }
```

Comment: Try `Scripting.IDictionary` instead of `Scripting.DictionaryClass`.

Comment: So IDictionary for the function parameters? Do I then cast it to dictionaryclass inside of the function or can I use it normally just like that?

Comment: As long as you're passing it from script, just try using it like that, without casting.

Comment: I don't seem to be having any more success with this either. I posted the code in an edit above.

Comment: Not just `IDictionary` (which could be [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary(v=vs.110).aspx)), but `Scripting.IDictionary`.

Comment: I got the same thing. I updated my code to show the new thing I tried. Should I be changing the classic asp code at all? I haven't touched that yet. All I've been changing is the C# code block that I've been posting.

Comment: Apparently, you need to show the code for `report.GetReport(Report_Params)`, where the error is thrown. You can also try `dynamic` instead of hard typing for `Report_Params`.

Comment: The error is thrown in classic ASP, I don't even get into the C# code unless I set the parameter to object. If I set it to anything with dictionary I get "Invalid Procedure call or argument" for this statement "test.GetReport 1, dic"

Comment: Report_Params as object works, so it's only a matter of what you need to do with the passed in Report_Params object. What is the code you want to execute on the scripting dictionary?

Comment: Yes, Report_Params as an object gets me into the C# library. I want to be able to access the keys and values inside the dictionary. In my example at top (classic ASP) I added a key "Test" with value 1. I would like to be able to access 1 using the key test on that dictionary. Eventually I'll be making a report with the key value pairs coming in but since I can't get it to be visible I haven't implemented that code, hence why all code paths return null at the moment. I use the breakpoint inside to check the values of report_param.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 - when you answer a comment, make sure you prepend '@' and the target name, or we are not notified of your comment. I just happened to check back this question today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with the following:

It seems that when an object gets passed from Classic ASP to a COM object, it MUST be passed as an object, therefore the final definition is:

```
public byte[] GetReport(int Report_Type_Requested, object Report_Params)
```

In order to cast that object to the dictionary object I found out about the Marshal class from googling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.100).ASPX

Making the line I needed:

```
Scripting.DictionaryClass Report_Dictionary = (Scripting.DictionaryClass)Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(Report_Params, typeof(Scripting.DictionaryClass));
```

I was then able to use the dictionary in my code.

I was also able to use this technique to bring in ADODB.Recordsets over the COM as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work (you need to reference the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" COM object of course):

```
    public byte[] GetReport(int Report_Type_Requested, object Report_Params)
    {
        Scripting.Dictionary dic = (Scripting.Dictionary)Report_Params;
        foreach (string key in dic)
        {
            object value = dic.get_Item(key);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Doing that is what gives me the "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'Scripting.DictionaryClass'. COM components that enter the CLR and do not support IProvideClassInfo or that do not have any interop assembly registered will be wrapped in the __ComObject ..." error

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted that from the error from my original question but I still had the same error just with Scripting.Dictionary.

Comment: It works fine for me. You should share a repro project.